# Increasing samples of a signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi everybody I have a simple matrix like this Ex = [ 1 5; 2 5; 4 15; 5 15; 7 25; 8 25]; and it is graph is like below. I want to keep the same shape of the signal with more samples. In other words I need to have more rows in my matrix with corresponding values in between, keeping the same behaviour. Thanks for help. ,[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you want to look into is interpolation, in this case linear interpolation would do nicely.  There's a good blog post on this topic [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/25/piecewise-linear-interpolation/).

The gist is that you can do what you are after using the [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function, like so:

```
Ex = [ 1 5; 2 5; 4 15; 5 15; 7 25; 8 25];
x_points = [1:0.5:8]; 
y_points = interp1(Ex(:,1),Ex(:,2),x_points,'linear');
Ex2 = [x_points' y_points'];
```

This should generate y_points for each of the specified x_points and then combine them into a matrix similar to the input (but with more rows).

Comment: If interpolation speed is a concern, you should take a look at this submission in the MATLAB File Exchange and its comments: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43325-quicker-1d-linear-interpolation--interp1qr

Comment: May I ask another question is there a way to specify sample number than the distance between the samples. Lets say I want to make a signal with 28 samples a signal with 32.450 samples. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "make a signal with 28 samples a signal with 32.450 samples", since at first glance it seems like you want a non integer number of rows in your matrix.

Comment: I mean I have a 28*2  matrix which its graph is like above I want to make it 32.450*2 matrix which will give me a similar graph. Thanks.

Comment: Well, to change the rows you get out you just need to change the x_points vector. I only used `1:0.5:8` as a quick off the cuff example, just create a vector of ascending numbers of the desired length. To clarify, when you write "32.450" you mean "thirty two thousand four hundred and fifty", right?

Comment: Thanks for your help I figured out that later.